# write a function called which takes in an array of number and return the product of them all

Tags: python-3.x, recursion

def productOfarray(arr=[1,23,4]):
        if arr==[0]:
            return 0`
        return n*productOfarray(n+1)
   
    print(productOfarray(arr)

Comment: Unclear what your question is, but your print statement is missing a closing parentheses, and I think you defined `arr` in the wrong place, and what is `n`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to find a product of a list, checkout the code example below:

```py
from array import array

def array_product(array):
    result = 1
    for n in array: # loop through each list item
         result = result * n # calculate product
    return array("key", result)
```

Comment: Thanks but in array how I do